# How to add bullets to text view in android

Tags: java, android, layout

It's hard to explain, and I don't really know how to say it in english so I have a screenshot that shows what I mean. The following image is what I want in my layout, and I'm asking you if any of you knows how to create this in to my text.

[image]

If you need any of my codes, feel free to ask and I will edit them in to it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By *dots*, do you mean the bullets?

Comment: Use this character code for bullets `\u2022`

Comment: Yeah well didn't know that they were called Bullets in english. Thanks though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These dots are represented by `\u2022` char